# Why does the Cat Priest from 'Waiting for God' have a blackened hand?

Tags: red-dwarf

In [Waiting For God](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0684186/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm), the cat priest, played by [Noel Coleman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0171168/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t5) has a blackened hand.

The [wiki page](https://reddwarf.fandom.com/wiki/Cat_Priest) says this about it:

> Like most cats have different colourations on the same body, the Cat Priest has one black hand and one white hand.

However there's no source for this information.

The only reference I can find is to the biblical miracle [Healing the man with a withered hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healing_the_man_with_a_withered_hand). Which might be relevant due to that cat's clerical position?

Comment: I've never heard of the source material, but FWIW, the obvious reason for a cat to have one blackened paw is because [that's the paw he used to grab the chestnuts out of the fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_and_the_Cat).

Comment: @quuxplusone oddly I've never heard of that. Not sure if that would be relevant to this character though. I guess he is duped by Lister.

Answer (score 11):

The information about the black hand, is actually from the [DVD Liner notes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0684186/trivia?item=tr3496598).

> The Cat Priest has one white hand and one black hand; according to the DVD liner notes, this is because the Felis sapiens, like their ancestors, often had patches of different colours.

The reason listed in the wiki page is accurate.